# How much memory is typically used per user DOM in Server Side Blazor?

Tags: blazor-server-side

I know blazor server-side retains the DOM of each user in memory and uses signal-r to update the browser DOM each time an event fires, I want to know the memory footprint to retain this DOM in memory per user for a typical medium sized page in a web app? My another question is if fast events like mouse move that constantly updates the page are practical in this framework?

Answer (score 4):

[Here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/blazor-server-in-net-core-3-0-scenarios-and-performance/) is an article about this topic (my highlights):

> **Using Blazor Server at scale**
>
> Blazor Server can scale from small internal line of business apps to large internet scale apps. While .NET Core 3.0 was still in preview we tested Blazor Server to see what its baseline scale characteristics look like. We put a Blazor Server app under load with active clients and monitored the latency of the user interactions. In our tests, a single Standard_D1_v2 instance on Azure (1 vCPU, 3.5 GB memory) could handle over 5,000 concurrent users without any degradation in latency. A Standard_D3_V2 instance (4 vCPU, 14GB memory) handled well over 20,000 concurrent clients. The main bottleneck for handling further load was available memory. **Will you see this level of scale in your own app? That will depend in large part on how much additional memory your app requires per user. But for many apps, we believe this level of scale out is quite reasonable.**